# Change the amount of times code checks number

Tags: c#

```
            Console.Write("Enter -");
            string input = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
            string ascii = input;
            byte[] ASCIIValues = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ascii);
            for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
            {
                if (ASCIIValues[i] >= 48 && ASCIIValues[i] <= 57)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Is number");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Is not number");
                }
            }
```

I have made a code where it checks if you have entered number or not. It works fine while using only numbers from 1 to 9 . When I enter number with more digits the code checks each number. For example I enter 100 , and the code shows 3 lines "Is number."  How could I change it , to only showing 1 line of "Is number."

Comment: No loop, just do: `if (ASCIIValues.All(code => code >= 48 && code <= 57)) { Console.WriteLine("Is number"); } else { Console.WriteLine("Is not number"); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats very complicated code for such a simple task

```
        Console.Write("Enter -");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        if(input.All(c=>Char.IsDigit(c)))
             Console.WriteLine("Is number");
        else
             Console.WriteLine("Is not a number");
```

or you could do this (since the next thing I expect you to do is convert that input to a number)

```
        Console.Write("Enter -");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        int num;
        if (Int32.TryParse(input, out num))
            Console.WriteLine("is a number");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("is not a number");
```

TryParse tries to convert the string to a number and reports success or failure

Answer (score 0):

You are reading each char in the whole string and printing the result for each char... To follow your approach you should be checking the whole string first and print a positive result only if all char check was verified as a number.

Try something like this:

```
// ... your previous code
bool result = true;
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    if (ASCIIValues[i] >= 48 && ASCIIValues[i] <= 57)
        continue;
    else
    {
        result = false;
        break;
    }

if (result == true)
    Console.WriteLine("Is number");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Is not number");
```

Here I'm initializing a bool variable `result` with `true` value. If the code runs until the end of the loop with no `break` call, it would be considered a number. Otherwise, it would be `false`

Note: the [`char.IsNumber(char inputChar)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isnumber?view=net-6.0) function is a System's library function that does something like what you did with ASCII code checks. Using it, your code should look like this:

```
public static bool IsNumeric(string input)
{
    if(input.Length == 0)
        return false;
    
    for(int i = 0; i <input.Length; i++)
        if(!char.IsNumber(input[i]))
            return false;
           
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that there is a bug in that logic: if the input is empty, the code will result in a false positive. The other answer provides a more clear way to solve the problem using `Linq` and it is the kind of code you should face in production applications. I bet you are just starting to learn the language, and certainly, Linq should be on your roadmap.